# Laravel preselect in a dropdown menu

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to pre-select a value for my dropdown but do not know what to put in order for the equivalence comparison. My current code is below:

```
{!! Form::select('suggest_organization',Organization::pluck('organization_name', "organization_recordid"),$organization->organization_recordid,['class'=> 'form-control selectpicker','id' => 'suggest_organization','data-live-search' => 'true','data-size' => '5']) !!}
```

I suppose the space I put $organization->organization_recordid is where I should do the pre-selection. The value that I want to select is {{$service->organizations()->first()->organization_name}}, however, I need to select from the Organization::pluck('organization_name', "organization_recordid") table with equivalent value. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the key to make an option pre selected. in your select, `organization_name` is the value and `organization_recordid` is the key for options. so just put the service `organization_recordid` as the third parameter and it will be pre selected.

```
{!! Form::select('suggest_organization', Organization::pluck('organization_name',  "organization_recordid"), $service->organizations()->first()->organization_recordid ?? '',  ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker', 'id' => 'suggest_organization', 'data-live-search' => 'true', 'data-size' => '5']) !!}
```

here i have added null coalescing operator to check for value existence. it will check if the value exists or put an empty string. you have to have php 7.3+ for using null coalescing operator. if your php version is below 7.3, you can use a ternary if condition.

```
$service->organizations()->first() ? $service->organizations()->first()->organization_recordid : ''
```